# .add days return wrong value

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, momentjs

I don't know why but when I get the date from `FullCalendar` and try to edit this seems that `moment.js` overwrite all date saved. For example:

```
var date_start = $calendar.fullCalendar('getView').start.toDate();
date_start.setHours(0);
var date_end = $calendar.fullCalendar('getView').start.toDate();
date_end.add(1, "days");
console.log("start => " , date_start);
console.log("end => " , date_end)
```

result returned:

> start =>  Sat Oct 24 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (ora legale Europa occidentale)
>   end =>  Sat Oct 24 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (ora legale Europa occidentale)

and this is wrong 'cause the end date should be:

> end =>  Sun Oct 25 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (ora legale Europa occidentale)

NB: I save the end date as start the date 'cause I'm using this [extension](https://github.com/mherrmann/fullcalendar-columns/) and actually have a bug on the day, infact the resource is splitted in more day into a single day (read the doc for more details). 

My problem's related to the `date_end.add(1, "days");` seems infact this code replace the all date returned from start date to the `date_start` variable.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JackIlpazzo/jc07k3dd/27/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are working with the same date object reference each time.

Create a new object for the second one

```
   var date_start = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getView').start.toDate();
    date_start.setHours(0);
    // create new instance
    var date_end = moment(date_start);
    date_end.add(1, "days");
    console.log("start => " , date_start);
    console.log("end => " , date_end.toDate());
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jc07k3dd/28/)**</kbd>

Comment: Now I know what I did wrong. Thank you man, have a nice day :)

Comment: If you have time maybe you could check my other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33320164/how-to-get-the-details-of-appointment-in-shift-event-fullcalendar

Comment: not familiar with that columns extension, but should be tied into UI events I would think

Comment: Okay, but if you have time to take a look I'll be happy.